# Divide shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, data

I'm new working with QGIS 1.8.0 and wanted to know if its possible to subdivide a map (shapefile, which is round-like) into small squares but following the outer round contour of the map? I tried with the vector grid tool but the subdivision does not limit to the map and I get only a big square. Any ideas?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: please provide a sketch of your desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a vector grid using the "extents from layer" and specifying the grid size. In the example below I've used 10km x 10km grid squares. Make sure to output the grid as polygons, not as lines.

`Vector > Research Tools > Vector grid`

[image: vector grid dialog]

This will produce a regular grid with the specified extents and cell size:

[image: inputs]

Next, you need to intersect the layer you want to subdivide with the grid.

`Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect`

[image: intersect]

The result is shown below. I imagine this is what it would look like if you hit an apple hard enough with a tennis racket. Each part of the intersected features will have all of the attributes from the input layers.

[image: result]

Comment: Very, very good explained thank you! The only thing is that the loading bar in the pop up window stays at 100% and then it crashes, any other tip?! sorry...

Comment: it doesn't crash, it does creates another .shp file but when I open it its blank...

Comment: Its working now, very strange, but thanks so much anyways! I got the image!